# Minimal static compilation in mruby

Tags: c, static, compilation, mruby

I have a simple example:

```
#include "mruby.h"
#include <mruby/compile.h>

int main() 
{
    mrb_int i; 
    mrb_value c;
    mrb_state *mrb = mrb_open();
    char kod[] = "def suma(a,b) (a+b).to_i end";

    if (!mrb) { /* problemy */ } 
    mrb_load_string(mrb, kod);

    for(i=0; i<9; i++) 
    { 
        c = mrb_funcall(mrb, mrb_top_self(mrb), "suma",  2,
                mrb_fixnum_value(i), mrb_fixnum_value(i)); 
    }
    mrb_close(mrb);
return 0;
}
```

How can I  compile it in static mode, **without** the library `libmruby.a`?
I only want to add `/src/*.c` file(s).

I don't need `Array`. No file access, no other gems (`time`, `test`, `sprintf`, `random`, etc.)

Which files are important and which can I pass by?
I do not need the gem compiler. I can run only bytecode if it is possible.

How can I do this?

Comment: In the edit I was partly guessing what you meant, the grammar and spelling mistakes making it hard to understand what you write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must run **rake** in the mruby source directory. You will have produce libmruby.a in the build/host/lib directory. (in a specyfic architecture)

Next you compile your program with **-I option** and you link your program with **-lmruby** specified to the linker.

Is no possible making normal static like as lua